# c# wpf open new window based on application

Tags: c#, wpf, window

I wanted to ask if it's possible to open new window in relation to main application ? Currently i'm using `System.Windows.Window.Left/Right`
But it's only in relation to the desktop.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you precise what you mean by "in relation" please ? Is that about the position ?

Comment: Yes, it's about the position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use  WindowStartupLocation property to set where the window should be Showed.

in XAML

```
<Window WindowStartupLocation="CenterParent">
```

or in Code

```
WindowStartupLocation=WindowStartupLocation.CenterOwner
```

Or you can set like follows

```
this.Left = mainWindow.Left + (mainWindow.Width - this.ActualWidth) / 2;
this.Top = mainWindow.Top + (mainWindow.Height - this.ActualHeight) / 2;
```

Comment: But is it possible to do it based on coordinates ? like 10 X and 10 Y from (0,0) of my application ?

Answer (score 1):

One easy way is to use the position of the main window. Something like this:

```
OtherWindow other = new OtherWindow();
other.Top = mainWindow.Top + 20;
```